# Howto use window functions in update statement?

Tags: sqlite

I have an easy SQL schema (SQLite), with this definition:

```
tbl_data (`id` INTEGER, `value` INTEGER, `result` INTEGER);
```

It has a few records (sample):

[image]

And I want to *UPDATE* this table to set *result=1* if *value>10* AND if no preceeding line contains *value>10*.

Preceeding limitation should be **2**, and order is the *id*.

So the desired goal is to have this:

[image]

Here is my playground: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5b1cfa5d4b4c78bd31f7427eca20b0b5

The actual table which I need to update contains >800k rows, so efficiency matters.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Why is the second 11 (record id = 3) not updated?

Comment: Hi, thank you! Because preceeding limit should be 2. So I only want to update the result if neither from two preceeding records contains value>10. In id=3, this constraint is not succeed, as id=1 contains a value>10, hence id=3 should not be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte1 as (
 select id, value, lag(value,1,0) over w as prev1, lag(value,2,0) over w as prev2
 from tbl_data
 window w as (order by id)
),
cte2 as (
 select id
 from cte1
 where value > 10
 and prev1 <= 10
 and prev2 <= 10
)
update tbl_data 
set result = 1
where id in (select id from cte2);
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what the code in your answer is doing?

Comment: @J.D. Search "common table expression mysql", you will find many articles written by people who can explain the concept way better than me.

Comment: I don't need to research it myself personally, as I'm familiar with concept, but many others who see your answer could use the explanation so they can learn better. Generally, some details are preferable for an answer.